# Why does Chrome drain more battery compared to Edge beta?

Tags: google-play-services

I'm currently using Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge together on the same smartphone. They share the same data, book marks etc. But even with data saver chrome kills the battery.

Not related: Even on the PC it's the same, chrome eats more resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On going investigation points out to the sync feature, and play services hurting the battery pack and using up RAM.

1. Chrome is draining the battery at 5% per 20 minutes.
2. Edge is at 2% per 20 minute drain interval.

Same forums, same accounts.